# Problem extracting emails with python-selenium

Tags: python, email, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I have a function to extract the email contact from websites. The problem is that sometimes it finds the email sometimes not.

I have tried the following function. In the code, there is an example of a websites where it finds the email and another where it cant be found.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions import presence_of_element_located 
from selenium.common.exceptions import NoSuchElementException
from selenium.common.exceptions import WebDriverException
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By


options =  webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver_path = 'C:\\Users\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe'


driver = webdriver.Chrome(driver_path, chrome_options=options)
wait =  WebDriverWait(driver,5)

website1 = 'restauranteelpicaporte.es' #INFO@RESTAURANTEELPICAPORTE.ES -> CANT FIND
website2 = 'restaurante-laparra.com' #laparramadrid@gmail.com ----------> FOUND

driver.get('http://www.google.es/maps/')
time.sleep(2)

def get_email(url):
    driver.execute_script("window.open('');")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'mailto:')]")
        email_addr = email.get_attribute("href").replace("mailto:", "")
    except:
        email_addr = ""

    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
    return email_addr

time.sleep(2)
email1 = get_email('https://'+website1)
email2 = get_email('https://'+website2)

time.sleep(2)
print("email1:",email1)
print("email2:",email2)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's because the first website which is "restauranteelpicaporte.es" does not have any mail info. The mail info rather lies inside the "contacto" tab for which the URL is 'restauranteelpicaporte.es/contacto/'.

Here is the working code snippet:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--start-maximized')
options.add_argument('--disable-extensions')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

website1 = 'restauranteelpicaporte.es/contacto/'
website2 = 'restaurante-laparra.com'

def get_email(url):
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(2)
    try:
        email = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[contains(@href, 'mailto:')]")
        email_addr = email.get_attribute("href").replace("mailto:", "")
    except:
        email_addr = ""

    return email_addr

email1 = get_email('https://'+website1)
email2 = get_email('https://'+website2)

print("email1:",email1)
print("email2:",email2)
```

ouput:

```
email1: info@restauranteelpicaporte.es
email2: laparramadrid@gmail.com
```